# Python InstaBot Error Message "Out of Follows for today"

Tags: python, bots, instagram, instagram-api

i´ve written a script to follow an account I´ve set in the Code, and after it followed the set amount of people (about 60 accounts) it just stops and leaves this error message:

```
`Attempting to follow: hyp_27
2021-09-24 12:40:54,562 - INFO - Going to follow `user_id` 12569454623.
2021-09-24 12:40:54,562 - INFO - Out of follows for today.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kidd\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\main1", line 20, in <module>
    if i > FollowCount:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
2021-09-24 12:40:54,567 - INFO - Total follows: 89/73
2021-09-24 12:40:54,567 - INFO - Total requests: 1572
```

and here is the code to my script

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot(follow_delay=15)
bot.login(username="munchey.memes", password="KiddCm200")

Account = input("Enter the Account name:")

followers = bot.get_user_followers(Account)
FollowCount = input("How many People do you want to follow")

i = 0
for user in followers[105:]:
    username = bot.get_username_from_user_id(user)
    print("Attempting to follow:", username)
    if bot.follow(username):
        i += 1
        print("Followed! -", username)
    else:
        print("Not Followed ! - ", username)
        if i > FollowCount:
            break
i = 0
for user in reversed(following[:-100]):
    username = bot.get_username_from_user_id(user)
    print("Attempting to Unfollow:", username)
    if bot.unfollow(username):
        i += 1
        print ("Unfollowed -", username)
    else:
        print("Failed to Unfollow-", username)
        if i > FollowCount:
            break

how can i fix this issue ?
```

Comment: You realize you left the username and password in your source code, right?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: Oh my, thanks a lot i didn’t realise !